# Explain and example about 'get', 'delete', 'post', 'put', 'options', 'patch', 'head' method?

Tags: http-method

I'm writing a webservice. Could any one explain these above methods and give me some example about them? Thank for your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 16):

**GET** should be used to **retrieve data** with no other effect however you can use query params in url to post data using get but it is not a safe method.

The **POST** method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.Generally used to **create** new entity.

The **PUT** method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. Generally used to **update** existing entity.

The **PATCH** method applies **partial modifications** to a resource

The **DELETE** method requests that the origin server **delete** the resource identified by the Request-URI.

The **TRACE** method echoes the received request so that a client can see what (if any) changes or additions have been made by intermediate servers.

The HTTP **CONNECT** method method **starts two-way communications** with the requested resource. It can be used to open a tunnel usually to facilitate SSL-encrypted communication (HTTPS) through an unencrypted HTTP proxy.

The **OPTIONS** method allows the client to **determine the options** and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

**HEAD** Retrieve all resources in a collection (header only) i.e. The HEAD method asks for a response identical to that of a GET request, but without the response body. This is useful for retrieving meta-information written in response headers, without having to transport the entire content.

From [this_link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) you can get a detail about these methods.I have used these resources to write these methods in short.

You can also get simplified details on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) wikipidea page.
This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch/31698882) link is also very descriptive for http methods.

And for the **implementation par**t this open source [Django_rest_code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py) at github can be a very good example to look at how to implement these Http methods in Django(Python).

Answer (score 2):

They are actions from the perspective of the client:

GET refers to the client requesting information in the form of a URL request to the server ie loading a web page full of data.

POST is the client sending information back to the server ie clicking submit on a text field.

PUT is very similar to POST except that the information sent back to the server must be identified under the supplied Request-URI

DELETE requests that the server delete the entity that the client has designated ie removing a blog post from your blog tells the server to forget that information.

Those are the 4 main methods through which clients and servers communicate, thus how information on the server is displayed to and controlled by the client.